# Getting rid of "FG" in a LTL equation

Tags: model-checking, linear-temporal-logic

i am currently struggling with a Linear temporal logic equation: $$\phi=FG( \lnot a\lor X \lnot a )$$
For my understanding, it means that starting at a certain point in the future, proposition a can never be reached again due to the definiton of "finally globally".

Now we have to transform it into an aquivalent equation that only contains the "Until" (U) "Next" (X), $\lnot$ and $\land$ operator.

My first approach was "everything allowed until never a again" but for that i would need "F" or "g" again, or am i getting something wrong?

Thinking about this problem for quite some days now, my prof said it was pretty easy but i just cannot figure it out, i hope some of you guys can help me :D
Thanks in advance! Enjoy your day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full solution, but a guide:
First, note that the meaning of $G$ is "always" (or "globally"), not "never".
Thus, $FG$ means "from a certain point and on" (or in LTL phrasing: eventually always).
The intuitive meaning of the formula $FG(\neg a\vee X\neg a)$ is that from somepoint and on, either you see $\neg a$ now, or in the next step.

However, all this is unnecessary in order to convert the formula to the temporal operator $U$ -- the operators $F$ and $G$ are built from $U$, and the translation is completely mechanical, using the following definitions:

- $F\phi=\text{true}U \phi$
- $G\phi=\neg F\neg \phi$

Simply apply these rules, and you'll have your formula.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. So at first, i apply the second rule to get $F \lnot F \lnot ( \lnot a \lor X \lnot a ) $ . After that the first one + DeMorgan to then have $true U ( \lnot true U ( a \land  X a ) ) $ ? I Know the concept of tautology and contradiction but the combination of $\lnot$ and Until is confusing me. Thank you in advance for your patience

Comment: Yes. Looks good.